# "Help" for JavaFX 2.2/8 applications

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to create an interactive help system for the UI elements of my JavaFX application.

I am wondering if there are ready solutions for this problem. I want something that will support these features:

1. I need a tooltip to be shown when the user hovers a mouse over the UI element ( the tooltip should contain help on this element).
2. I need the new window to appear when the user presses the "help" key on the keyboard.
   The window should contain full help information about the element that the mouse is hovering over.

I've found this question on SO that helps to find the similar system for swing:

[Best online help system for a large Java Swing project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820672/best-online-help-system-for-a-large-java-swing-project)

I need a solution for JavaFX.

Thanks.

Comment: [Just use Tooltips?](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/tooltip.htm)  If not, please edit your question and describe what you are asking and have tried more explicitly.

Comment: The question was edited. @jewelsea

Answer (score 2):

You may try just create a new stand-alone stage with a single  embedded browser and use a lot of html pages to compose your help system.
To not have to deal with those lot of files, you can put all into a single jar file and call it from your application. 
I think it can be used by any kind of application, changing only the html content. 
Is it?